# TFS Back-up Notifications

Tags: tfs

Our company uses TFS 2018. We have an annoying issue when there is TFS back-up failed,it sends notifications to hell lot of people which are invalid or unncecessary users. This list is in the domain Admins. I can't delete them manually.

Is there a script to delete the users or modify the sending list?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your primary issue is that you have this group of users in the `[Team Foundation]\Team Foundation Administrators` group or possibly many users added with privileges to the Administration Console Users, which is unusual.  To adjust who is part of the Team Foundation Administrators group:

1. RDP to the server that hosts the application tier for your TFS installation
2. Open the TFS Administration Console
3. Highlight the Application Tier
4. Click the Group Membership link
5. Double-click `[Team Foundation]\Team Foundation Administrators`
6. Adjust membership of the group

To learn more about configuring administrators from the TFS Administration console, see [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/add-administrator?view=azure-devops) on the topic.